# JAX-RS Generic Exception Mapper not working as expected

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using jersey 2.29.

I have written single exception mapper class to catch all the exceptions. But only some of the exceptions are getting caught.

For example when I throw my custom exceptions i.e. BusinessException, ConfigException then the mapper is invoked. But when there is internal server error then it is not getting invoked.

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GenericExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {

        ErrorMessage errorMessage = null;

        int errorCode = Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode();

        if (exception instanceof BusinessException) {

            logger.debug("BusinessException:", exception);

            BusinessExceptionType businessExceptionType = ((BusinessException) exception).getErrorCode();

            switch (businessExceptionType) {

            case NOT_FOUND:

                errorCode = Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode();
                break;

            case NOT_AUTHORISED:

                errorCode = Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode();
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }

        } else if (exception instanceof ConfigException) {

            logger.fatal("ConfigException:", exception);

        } else if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {

            logger.error("WebApplicationException:", exception);

            Response response = ((WebApplicationException) exception).getResponse();
            errorCode = response.getStatus();
        }

        else {

            logger.fatal("GenericException:", exception);
        }

        errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(errorCode, exception.getMessage());
        return Response.status(errorCode).entity(errorMessage).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

For Business Exception the error is a proper JSON:

```
{
    "errorCode": 404,
    "errorMessage": "Not found"
}
```

For any other server issue the error message is not a JSON:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        b {
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
        }

        .line {
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #525D76;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
    <p><b>Message</b> A MultiException has 3 exceptions. They are:</p>
    <p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
    </p>
    <p><b>Exception</b></p>
    <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AccountService,parent=AccountResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1554545299)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of in.pnb.ebanking.ws.resource.AccountResource errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on in.pnb.ebanking.ws.resource.AccountResource

    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre>
    <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
    <pre>A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AccountService,parent=AccountResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1554545299)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of in.pnb.ebanking.ws.resource.AccountResource errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on in.pnb.ebanking.ws.resource.AccountResource

    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:65)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:226)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:754)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:717)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre>
    <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
    <pre>org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AccountService,parent=AccountResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1554545299)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:51)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:188)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:59)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:754)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:717)
    org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre>
    <p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.30</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected:

```
{
    "errorCode": 500,
    "errorMessage": "There was an error processing your request."
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to catch MultiException separately?

Comment: It didnt work. May be because  MultiException is also a subclass of Throwable.